# GyroToUnity Quaternion Derivation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

Recently I develop a VR project so need use gyroscope,here is a code which I found in unity manual:

```
// The Gyroscope is right-handed.  Unity is left handed.
// Make the necessary change to the camera.
void GyroModifyCamera()
{
    transform.rotation = GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude);
}

private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
{
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```

Sorry for m poor math and English, can anyone give me some guide to explain the meaning of `GyroToUnity` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gyro `Input.gyro.attitude` sensor value is returned in *Right-Handed coordinates* but Unity uses the *Left-Handed coordinates* system. You can read about about both coordinate system [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/12048-lefthandedtorighthanded.pdf).

*A simple Image that illustrates the difference:*

[image]

The `GyroToUnity` function is simply used to do conversion from Gyro(Right-Handed coordinates) to Camera (Left-Handed coordinates). It looks like it is  flipping the direction of the *up/down* and *left/right* values from the Gyro sensor when the device is moving. After it is flipped, the new flipped value is returned and then assigned to the camera.

This is where the conversion/flipping is done:

```
return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
```

Hence the `-q.z` and `-q.w`. The minus sign is used to flip the values.

*What happens if the conversion is performed or if the `GyroToUnity` function is not used?*

If the device is attached to your face and you move your head up, the camera would move down and vice-versa. If you move it right, the camera would move left and vice-versa. This is supposed to be doing the opposite. That's why that function is used.

---

The easiest way to see what's happening is if you try it yourself. Bypass the `GyroToUnity` function then test it. You will see the difference.

```
void GyroModifyCamera()
{
    transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
}
```

Now, compare it with the original version of the code:

```
void GyroModifyCamera()
{
    transform.rotation = GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude);
}
```

Comment: en, i kown it's a coordinate conversion,but i why use this function can convert? maybe before ask this question  I should learn more mathf, thx